# Is there a way to use vba to open a second excel workbook without blocking the code in the first?

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to use an Excel application to launch other Excel Workbooks. I need the parent app to also be able to monitor the child app to see when it has closed, and (most importantly) to force the child app to close if it runs longer than expected.

I have tried the following solutions, but they both stop the parent app until the child app closes.

```
 Sub main()

    Dim wbPath As String
    wbPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\app1.xlsm"

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=wbPath, ReadOnly:=True)
    
    Application.Run "'" & wb.Name & "'!Go"
    
    MsgBox "before closing 1", vbOKCancel
    
    wb.Close
    
    MsgBox "app 2!", vbOKCancel
    
End Sub


Sub main2()

    Dim wbPath As String
    wbPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\app1.xlsm"

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    
    xlApp.Workbooks.Open wbPath, , True
    
    xlApp.Visible = True
    
    MsgBox "before closing 1 new instance", vbOKCancel
    
    Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Is there a way for a parent Excel application to launch another (child) workbook but still be able to continue running to monitor the child app and force it closed if needed?

Comment: Control it from xlApp object?

Comment: I'd like to control the child instance (start macros and such) but I need to also look to see when it completes so that if it gets hung up somehow and is just never going to complete, I can force it to quit and move on to the next report. But when I launch another excel instance with xlApp, the code in the parent app stops running until the child app closes - stopping me from looping and watching for the child app to close.  I may be forced to place all 19 worksheets into a single workbook and just run it all from a single workbook.

Comment: It's hard to relate the description of your requirements to the code. Could you share a practical example of what you're trying to do and why you think you need another instance of Excel to do it?

Comment: I work in a small medical facility with 6 locations. They are as paranoid about HIPAA as they are ignorant of technology, so I am restricted currently to using Excel and Power BI to do their data analyzing and reports. I currently put out 19 different reports on different days. I thought I could use Excel/VBA to automate the running of the reports by handling the dates to run, saving and emailing of the reports. Also I hate code duplication - so a central control would help prevent that.

Comment: I could make each report completely independent and run them all from Windows Task Scheduler, but when something changes, that's 19+ places I have to change the code.

Comment: Plus coding each report separately leaves me little to no control if Power Query hangs because the incoming data file was changed/corrupted or some coding error creates an infinite loop. I need something to watch the reports and kill them if they run too long for any reason and re-run them later. My solution needs to be robust enough to not hang up the system without having to code for and foresee every possible problem (which is, of course, not possible).

Comment: I think I may just write an Excel/VBA app that will look up all running instances of Excel every 30 seconds, add them to a collection and if any are still running X minutes after they were first seen, kill them, log the kill and email the log to me once no Excel instances are detected for at least Y minutes. Then I can manually run those killed reports and correct any issues found.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it.  Create a workbook with the code routines to be executed - eg "Slave.xlsm".

Code in a regular module:

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim m_Running As Boolean

'called from the other excel instance
Public Function Running() As Boolean
    Running = m_Running
End Function

Sub RunReport_1()
    m_Running = True
    WasteTime 10 '<<< loop for 10 secs (mimic a long-running task)
    Debug.Print "done"
    m_Running = False
End Sub

Sub RunReport_2()
    m_Running = True
    WasteTime 20 '<<< loop for 20 secs (mimic a longer-running task)
    Debug.Print "done"
    m_Running = False
End Sub

'spend some time in a loop to mimic (eg) a long-running task
Sub WasteTime(secs As Long)
    Dim endAt
    endAt = Now + secs * (1 / 24 / 60 / 60)
    Do While Now < endAt
        DoEvents
    Loop
End Sub
```

In regular module in another workbook you have code which loads up "Slave.xlsm" into a new Excel instance, and calls the (eg) report methods, then waits some time period for them to complete.  If a method doesn't complete in the allotted time, terminate the other Excel instance and continue with the other methods.

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application   '<< Excel instance where "Slave.xlsm" runs

Sub RunReports()

    RunReport "RunReport_1", 15  'call a report and let it run up to 15 secs
    
    RunReport "RunReport_2", 15  'call another report 

End Sub

'run a method in Slave.xlsm and wait `maxSecs` for it to finish
Sub RunReport(reportSub As String, maxSecs As Long)
    Dim endAt, isRunning As Boolean
    
    If xlApp Is Nothing Then
        Set xlApp = New Excel.Application 'start another instance
        xlApp.Visible = True
        xlApp.Workbooks.Open "C:\Temp\Slave.xlsm"
    End If
    
    'trigger sub in second Excel instance without locking up this instance
    xlApp.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), reportSub
    
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2) 'wait for it to start
    endAt = Now + (maxSecs * (1 / 24 / 60 / 60))
    Do While Now < endAt
        isRunning = xlApp.Run("Running")
        Debug.Print reportSub & " running?", isRunning
        If Not isRunning Then Exit Do 'sub finished!
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    Loop
    
    If isRunning Then
        Debug.Print reportSub & " still running !"
        'run-time exceeded: terminate the other Excel process (Google for methods)
        Set xlApp = Nothing 'clear the Global so the next call creates a new instance
    Else
        Debug.Print reportSub & " complete !"
        'ran within allotted time...
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Will this code close the open workbook if an error has popped up a dialog box that is waiting for a person to click to close it?

Comment: You'd need to add the code for "terminate the other Excel process" but that should work, yes.  for example - https://www.devhut.net/vba-forcing-applications-to-close/

Comment: I only ask because Excel won't even let you close it manually with some errors until they are corrected - like trying to close Excel when a tab has no name (https://i.imgur.com/Ri5GOYI.png). I'll have to test it out Tuesday at work and see...